# composer change directory config.json

Tags: json, config, composer-php

I'm using a restricted user on my serveur and I try to deploy my private GitHub repository (without it works perfectly):

php composer.phar update

Composer return :

An existing OAuth token for Composer is present and will be reused
  [ErrorException]            file_put_contents(/srv/data/.composer/config.json): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

My user cannot write into /srv/data. How to change config.json location ?

I try php composer.phar config home /srv/data/web/vhosts/mywebsite

https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#usage
to change COMPOSER_HOME

The problem still persite...

any idea ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Updating the configuration for home from the command logically cannot work, composer needs to know where it's home is in order to load the configuration file.

`COMPOSER_HOME=/srv/data/web/vhosts/mywebsite/.composer php composer.phar update` will allow you to load a configuration file from `/srv/data/web/vhosts/mywebsite/.composer/config.json`.